# Prefetched css didn't work

Tags: html, css, prefetch

I want to prefetch a CSS file for the next view. However, the CSS file that the browser prefetched didn't work. That's my usage:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/modules/style/common.css">
```

And the `Network` in chromeDev shows:
[image]

When I give up using `prefetch` and directly import the CSS file as following, the css rule work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/modules/style/common.css">
```

And this time the `Network` in chromeDev shows:
[image]

The difference that I can observe is the `type` marked with a red box. Can anyone tell me how to solve this ? I have googled but no answer.

Comment: I am confused - you say that is working, what are you trying to solve?

Comment: Did you want `preload` instead of `prefetch`? According to MDN, "browsers will give prefetch resources a lower priority than preload ones"

Comment: The priority are different as @j08691 the prefetch image is lowest and the other is highest,

Comment: It works when I directly import CSS file. But when I use prefetch, the css rules in `common.css` didn't work. That's what I am trying to solve. @MartinChaov

Comment: What I want is to load the CSS file during browser idle time. That's the feature of `prefetch` while `preload` will cause the CSS file to be loaded before any other key resources. @j08691

Comment: Looks like after you prefetch the resource you will need to change the "rel" attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

The prefetch hint is only about prefetching resources which will be needed by a next page. Let's say you have 2 pages.

- /index
- /post

The post requires a `post.css` file. The index page "knows" that a user will navigate to the post page. So, the index page "tells" the browser to prefetch the `post.css`.

`<link rel="prefetch" href="/css/post.css">`

But, the post page should tell the browser to use it anyway.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/post.css">`

Since the `post.css` is already prefetched, the browser will serve it from the cache.

Btw, I am working on an open-source project (https://github.com/sirko-io/engine) which analyzes how users navigate on a site, thus, resources required on a next page can be prefeteched. The aim of the project is to automatically add prefetch hints when they make sense.